# hyphen separated string from complex object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
let person={
    id: 01,
    name:'john',
    age:'21',
    address:{
        city:{
            city_name:'Mumbai',
            pin:54321
        },
        state: 'Maharashtra',
        country:'india',
        street:'Main street'
    }
}
function flat(myobj){
    for (item in myobj)
    {
        if(typeof item === 'Object')
        {
            flat(item);
        }
        console.log(item+'-'+myobj[item]+'\n');
    }
}




flat(person);
```

> The above code which i tried

I am trying to convert this object into a flat hyphen separated string . but i got stuck while accessing nested object, I am getting out but is,

> id-1
>
> name-john
>
> age-21
>
> address-[object Object]

**my expected output**

> id-1
>
> name-john
>
> age-21
>
> address-city-city_name-mumbai-pin-54321-state-maharashtra-country-india....

any suggestion where i am wrong and any other optimization needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`item` is the objects *key*, thus `typeof item` is *always* `"string"`. You might want to check `typeof myobj[item] === "object"` instead ... Additionally you need a way to keep track of nested keys when doing the recursive call, that can be done by passing the previous keys with the call:

```
function flat(obj, prev = ""){
  for (let key in obj) {
     if(typeof obj[key] === "object") {
        flat(obj[key], prev + "-" + key);
     } else {
       console.log((prev ? prev + "-" : "") + key + ": " + obj[key]);
     }
   }
 }
```

Here's how I'd write that:

```
 function keyValuePairs(obj, prev = []) {
   for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
      if(typeof value === "object") {
         yield* keyValuePairs(value, [...prev, key]);
      } else yield [[...prev, key].join("-"), value];
   }
 }

 const result = Object.fromEntries(keyValuePairs({ /*...*/ }));
```

Comment: I am a noob is there any simple code that i can understand

Comment: Tried to provide a simpler version.